# Infinity scroll products with dummyjson

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I want to do endless scrolling so that after scrolling 20 more products and so on endlessly. I have a model and the api itself from there I take everything that is required. Everything is working out. But I need another 20 products to appear after scrolling to the end, like in aliexpress. How to do it?

```
@Composable
fun FeedProductsScreen(viewModel: ProductViewModel){
    val products by viewModel.productsLiveData.observeAsState(emptyList())

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.fetchProducts()
    }
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 5.dp),
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        content = {
            items(products) {product ->
                ProductCard(product)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

api code

```
interface MarketplaceApi {
    @GET("products")
    suspend fun getProducts(
        @Query("skip") skip: Int,
        @Query("limit") limit: Int
    ): ProductResponse

    companion object {
        fun create(): MarketplaceApi {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://dummyjson.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

            return retrofit.create(MarketplaceApi::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

viewmodel code

```
class ProductViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val repository = ProductRepository()
    val productsLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Product>>()

    private var currentPage = 0
    private val pageSize = 20

    fun fetchProducts() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val response = repository.fetchProducts(currentPage, pageSize)
                val products = response.products
                productsLiveData.value = products
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("ERROR: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried a lot of options but it didn't work out.I tried a lot of options but nothing came out. I tried through page numbering or through viewmodel management, but it still didn't work out.

Thank you!

Comment: I did it myself
**[my github project](https://github.com/v0nd1/MarketPlace)**